# Sensational clues

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, metapuzzles

Some of the clues are images, because it seems like you can't do colors on SE. Like in a previous puzzle from me, if you get any "subanswers", I'll confirm them. This doesn't count answers to a specific clue.

---

Interpret a particle with your nose, maybe

[image]

QGHF JZ OSSPJROA JPGHGFOEGFH ZPJI PJIOF EGIUQ

Amicable, often cheers people u, ind

Pick Nick kin sex

Value like seventy five or nine, unlike six or eight

[image]

GDFFDX QRBBWN FNEHDP RUNP IDL NKELCGEZDX SZEH XRFONLU CXP SDLPU.

Gossi tement that is not neccesarily true

Duel tomb am

Clothing's number

[image]

BUCS BSEX CYS DSBCSX UP E AGEBU CYEC YEM E BEZS

A 3d object eight, width and _____

Gay musing aim app

Between spaces in a sentence

[image]

C NEWTV RL BWTNVNBWVN, WT OVTBCON NWFVWLV YBW FCPVN LWRNV YRKB SVZZN

Animals like weasel hough with shorter tails

Ewes close

Flavour or scent, or one's basic nature

[image]

CWQIO GBOKT XTOHL RXT SMBOBSRIO RMBR HTTJC B HTR HKJI NKOLT

Membrane of the corti that for he inner ear

Howl land rad cliff

Comment: I've figured out several of the gimmicks here. This is fun!

Comment: (Just letting you know, Corti is a name. You probably have to change your second-last clue.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The **clues that look normal**

> have answers SNIFF OUT(?) / ODD / SIZE / WORDS / ESSENCE. Taking the center letters of each of the odd-length words gives **RAYLEIGH WAVES**. (And of course, since this has "sniffing out" and references to scent, it must be the *smell* meta.

The **colored clues**

> are ordinary clues. The answers are COLOR MONITOR, RUSSIA, REESE'S PIECES, BUMBLEBEE, and SECONDARIES. Each of those is associated with three colors, and each has the same number of letters as its clue has words. Taking the corresponding letters to the colors of the words gives **CROSS ASSEMBLER**.
>  [image]
>
>  Since this one relates to colors, it's the *sight* meta.

The **encrypted clues**

> can all be decrypted with substitution ciphers. The clues are:
>  - SIGN OF APPROVAL ORIGINATING FROM ROMAN TIMES
>  - COMMON PUZZLE METHOD USED FOR EXTRACTION WITH NUMBERS AND WORDS.
>  - NOTE NEAR THE CENTER OF A PIANO THAT HAS A NAME
>  - A SCORE IN HORSESHOES, OR PERHAPS SOMEONE WHO MAKES NOISE WITH BELLS
>  - SUPER MARIO WORLD TWO CHARACTER THAT LOOKS A LOT LIKE BIRDO
>
>  The answers to those are THUMBS UP, INDEXING, MIDDLE C, RINGER, and PINK YOSHI. Each of those starts with the name of a finger, so this is the *touch* meta. Taking the other letters (SUP/ING/C/ER/OSHI) and re-decrypting them gives **PERFECT CIRCLE**.

The clues with missing **parts of words**

> have all had an item of food removed. The original clues are:
>  -  Amicable, often cheers people up, or kind
>  - Gossip a statement that is not neccesarily true
>  - A 3d object has height, width and _____
>  - Animals like weasels although with shorter tails
>  - Membrane of the corti that form in the inner ear
>
>  The solutions are NICE, RUMOR, BREADTH, STOATS, and BASILAR, each of which has a food item in it. (Food means this is the *taste* meta.) Removing that food item from each gives **N OR TH ST AR**.

The **clues that look like random words**

> are all homophones of the actual clues, which are:
>  - Picnic insects
>  - Dual to ma'am
>  - Game using a map
>  - Use clothes
>  - Howell and Radcliffe
>
>  The answers to those are ANTS / SIR / RISK / WEAR / DANS, which sounds like ANSWER IS **SQUARE DANCE**. And since this was all about homophones, it's the *hearing* meta.

**Putting it all together**

> Each of the answers has two words, and one of the words in each is a [Zener card](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zener_cards) - the tools used to test for clairvoyance, the *sixth sense*.
>
>  PERFECT **CIRCLE**
>  **CROSS** ASSEMBLER
>  RAYLEIGH **WAVES**
>  **SQUARE** DANCE
>  NORTH **STAR**
>
>  Those have a canonical ordering (which I've helpfully arranged them into up there). Reading off the *n*th letter of the *n*th non-Zener-card word gives **PSYCH**, the final answer.

*(Thanks to Wesley Situ, n_palum, Sp3000, and Gareth McCaughan for their help in chat!)*

Comment: Although I didn't help thaaat much, I enjoyed watching it get solved. Super cool puzzle!